# Bundler issues in installing rails on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I have installed ruby 1.9.3 using rvm and after doing gem install rails, it says gem successfully downloaded, but when I type rails -v it gives me the following error:
Unable to activate rails-3.0.1, because bundler-1.5.1 conflicts with bundler (~> 1.0.0) (Gem::LoadError)

How do I fix this?

Comment: Looks like you have installed new bundler on your computer (1.5.1), but old rails (3.0.1) requires older bundler `~> 1.0.0`, that means you should use newer rails or older bundler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this:

```
rvm @global do gem uninstall bundler -ax
gem install bundler -v '~>1.0.0'
```

this will remove the globally installed bundler (available for all gemsets on this ruby) and install compatible local version only for current gemset.

Comment: This is a valid solution but it gives you issues later because the bundler versions required for ruby and rails become incompatiable. A better solution was to uninstall rails 3.0.1 and install rails 3.2.7

Comment: this is why you need to use gemsets, they separate projects so bundler from one project does not affect another, but as you can update why not rails 4?